# Xml feed prestashop - image url doesnt working

Tags: xml, image, prestashop, feed

I need help with prestashop xml feed. I have all but when I'm trying to show image, something goes wrong and image doesn't show (because of wrong link).

```
id_image=Product::getCover($product->id);
$product->cover=$Link->getImageLink('img/p/',$product->id,$id_image['id_image'].'-home');
```

and link show like this

```
<IMGURL>
    http://www.webpage.com/1-1885-home/img/p/.jpg
</IMGURL>
```

but I want have it like this

```
<IMGURL>
    http://www.webpage.com/img/p/1-1885-home.jpg
</IMGURL>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try this:

```
$link->getImageLink($product['link_rewrite'], $id_image[ 'id_image' ], 'thickbox_default')
```

It should return a full and nice URl to image! :)